# Controls inside the dynamically added web user control does not retain there value on post back caused by the dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

i am dynamically adding and removing a different user control from a to a place holders.

The user controls have lot of asp.net controls like cascading dropdowns with autopostback true.

The whole page is in a update panel.

After every postback i again add the control added previously and the which control is added previously is maintained in a view state.

The problem: Only first time the content in the textboxes get cleared after the first postback(caused by changing the dropdown)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your dynamic controls are being added in the Page_Init event in order for them to retain their data.

Comment: but inside the Page_Init event my viewstate["abc"] value is null ?

Comment: Yes, you need to create the controls in page_init, but the viewstate won't be available until page_load, so you need to separate the creation logic from the access logic.